# S3 GUI MacOS X client for large number of files

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, client

I'm looking for a **MacOS X GUI AWS S3 client** to handle listing of **very large number of files** and downloading some files from it.

### Context

I work in a company where we have a cloud-based product that store files on S3. Our buckets have millions of files now. Sometimes I need to be able to list those buckets and to pick some files to help me debug our application. Since the list is very long I would like to filter it to browse it more easily with a MacOS X GUI application. I would like to be able to download some files, and since the buckets are protected, it needs the HTTP header AWS signature. Ideally the client would treat the bucket as read-only, to prevent from making mistakes.

### Problem

I've searched on the internet for MacOS X clients with such features, but they all try to make some kind of hierarchical file system analogy which does not really stick with S3 API. In their analogy they have the concept of folders where the delimiter is `/`. If a "folder" contains a lot of keys, then browsing it will either needs to list all the keys, or some clients will list more keys as you scroll down.

For example I might have millions of keys which start with `data/` but only a few which start with `data/555` (note that the string does not end with a `/` character, the whole problem relies here)

### Solution

I'm considering writing a GUI client for MacOS X (and maybe Windows) that uses the `prefix` and `delimiter` query parameters of the S3 GET bucket listing :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Typically in the previous example, I would put the prefix as `data/555`

I want to know if I've overlooked a S3 GUI client which would have such features.

### Features

- GUI client for MacOS X (ie not a command line : I need non-tech coworkers to be able to use it)
- List bucket with arbitrary `prefix` and `delimiter` query parameters filter
- Be able to select files from filtered list and download them
- S3 Authorization (clients managing only one S3 account are welcome)
- Ideally a read-only client (would not contain code which could modify the bucket)

Thanks in advance for any info on that matter,

Raphael